# FastReport fetch data without DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, fastreport

I have this project on c# windows forms and what I have to do is get some data from a web service and present them to FastRaport.
I have tried display them on a DataGridView first and then fetching the data from it and it works pretty nice. I can download the file and then it gives me a dialog asking me in what format do I want to save it.
But now the requirement is to not use gridview at all, just a button that would convert directly those data into a PDF file.

Here's my code for displaying the data into DataGridView:

```
    var asd1 = dataGridView1.Columns.Add("DrzavaAng", "DrzavaAng");
    var asd2 = dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Valuta", "Valuta");
    var asd3 = dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Oznaka", "Oznaka");
    var asd4 = dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Nomin", "Nomin");
    var asd5 = dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Sreden", "Sreden");
    for (var i = 0; i<xmlNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        var node = xmlNodes[i];
        var states = new Class();

        states.Valuta = node["Valuta"].InnerText;
        states.Oznaka = node["Oznaka"].InnerText;
        states.Nomin = node["Nomin"].InnerText;
        states.Sreden = node["Sreden"].InnerText;
        states.DrzavaAng = node["DrzavaAng"].InnerText;

        //var asd = dataGridView1.Columns.Add("1", "1");
        _ = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["DrzavaAng"].Value=states.DrzavaAng;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Valuta"].Value=states.Valuta;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Oznaka"].Value=states.Oznaka;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Nomin"].Value=states.Nomin;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Sreden"].Value=states.Sreden;
    }
```

Here's the part where I pass the data from GridView to the FastReport "database".

```
        using (Report report = new Report())
        { 
            report.Load(ReportPath);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn cl in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add();
            }

            object[] clvl = new object[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<row.Cells.Count; i++)
                { clvl[i] = row.Cells[i].Value; }
                dt.Rows.Add(clvl);
            }
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            report.Dictionary.RegisterData(ds.Tables[0], "test", true);

            report.SetParameterValue("date", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")); 
            report.Show();
        }
```

Here's my FastReport file before committing anything:
[FastReportImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jibso.png)

And here's the output I get : [FastReport output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7rti.png)

My question is, how can I make it to fetch the data without the gridview, directly from webservice and load it into a FastReport -> PDF file?

Comment: You should create data table from xmlNodes

Comment: @Chetan, sorry I forgot to mention that part too, I already have an xmlNodes table and I'm using to transfer data to a GridView, and the from the gridview I transfering  to FastRaport. Now I just have to get rid of GridView and make it to communicate directly with FastReport.

Comment: You can not use xmlNodes table directly to FastReport?

Comment: I don't know how to use it, I've been trying a lot till now but nothing.

Comment: I can see that `xmlNodes` is not table but it is a list of XmlElement. Currently you are adding new columns to gridview and adding rows to it with data from xmlNodes. Instead of that why don't you create new data table and add columns to it and add rows to the table with data from xmlNodes?

Comment: @Chetan I don't really know how to achieve that. Can you please help me with a pseudo code at least or a reference link or something? I would really appreciate it.